# AWS Lambda Functions - Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When attempting to create a new hello world lambda I got this error:

[image]

This error is also happening when I attempt to run my tests on my existing functions.

Comment: Is your AWS console session still valid? Do the permissions associated with the logged-in user allow you to perform these actions? Does it work in a different browser?

Comment: This is embarrassing. I forgot I had an authentication header chrome extension turned on. It was overriding my auth token in aws. D:

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem quickly. What was the name of the Chrome extension? I ask so that you can document it here which might help someone in the future.

Comment: Its called ModHeader. Its used to add auth headers (or any headers really) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

Comment: Also thanks for your comment @jarmod, running it in Firefox is what made me realize it had something to do with my chrome browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is embarrassing. I forgot I had an authentication header chrome extension turned on. It was overriding my auth token in aws.

Don't do drugs kids.